# Creating new express project with nodeclipse gives blank project and "unexpected exception" error

Tags: eclipse, node.js

Just installed latest version of Edine from nodeclipse, and in the console that is the only message outside of path information for the directory the project is stationed in. Also tried grabbing the latest default version and tried to install via New Software with similar results.

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\express-work\1406755265579/test 
>   Unexpected Exception

Anyone had this ever work? All methods I'm finding online seem to be broken.

This is on Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that arrives at this question and has the same issue.

I was under the mistaken understanding that when installing Nodeclipse, it also installed node.js, express, and mongodb. This is not the case. Installing node.js and express resolved this issue.

Comment: How? what do you installed?